# Error on local host Chrome with React project, how can I avoid this issue?

Tags: reactjs, proxy, localhost, firewall, npm-start

For a few days now I have been encountering an issue while trying to npm start a template I have downloaded and opened on VS code. Everytime I start and that the project opens on my Chrome localhost server, this error is thrown :

localhost refused to connect.
Here are some suggestions:

Check the connection
Check the proxy and firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I have been trying a few things already, including :

- opening the file on my friend's VSC on his computer, there is no problem starting it on his local server
- Installing latest Node version
- Updating Chrome
- Re try to npm install all the packages and components
- I don't have firewall activated on my laptop

Nothing has worked...

Someone has already encountered a similar issue and could help me with that please ?

- opening the file on my friend's VSC on his computer, there is no problem starting it on his local server
- Installing latest Node version
- Updating Chrome
- Re try to npm install all the packages and components
- I don't have firewall activated on my laptop

I am expecting someone that maybe has encountered the same issue and could know what to do to resolve this ?